# QUnit: How to pass a global variable reference?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, sinon

I have a qunit module that doesn't allow a created object's method to see a global variable. The simplified version:

```
qunit.module("testcases", {
    setup: function () {
        var globalVar = "something";
    }
});
test("test1", function () {
   obj = new MyObj({});
   obj.execute(); // uses globalVar but doesn't see it 
});
```

How can I get the obj instance to recognize the globalVar?

I tried defining globalVar within test1 as well, but no luck.  I don't want to put the globalVar on the obj instance, since it's `execute` function doesn't check on itself for the global

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by anonymous superuser -- cannot use `var` in the setup function because it's actually closed off as it's own scope